# How to calculate time difference between current and previous row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table t1 like this :

[image: t1 table " temporally created table from previous query]

What i want to do is do calculations between all rows and save the value in new coloumn called diff

```
TICKETID| DATENEW  | DIFF
16743     12:36:46   0
16744     12:51:25   15.  minute  
16745     12:57:25   6.5  minute
..........
.......
etc
```

i know there are similar questions ,but ive tried all of the solutions 
posted here with no success,so how to solve this query ???

Comment: You'll need to join the table to a correlated subquery of itself. In Sql Server, you'd use LAG or LEAD window functions, which perform **much** better.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, can u kindly provide me with an example to make it more clear ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the time difference in minutes between the current and previous row, you can use `timestampdiff` on `datenow` and the previous time, which you can get via subquery:

```
select ticketid, datenew,
    timestampdiff(minute,datenew,(select datenew from mytable t2
        where t2.ticketid < t1.ticketid order by t2.ticketid desc limit 1)) as diff
from mytable t1
```

**Update**

Here's another way using a variable to store the previous `datenew` value that might be faster:

```
select ticketid, datenew, timestampdiff(minute,datenew,prevdatenew)
from (
    select ticketid, datenew, @prevDateNew as prevdatenew, 
      @prevDateNew := datenew
    from mytable order by ticketid
) t1
```

Comment: ya that 's solve my answer like a magic , but i need to know how @prevDateNew get the previous in the way you used it in this qury.., like if you kindly describe me how this query excute in steps , to learn more about MYSQL query

Comment: for each row (in order of `ticketid`), `@prevDateNew := datenew` stores `datenew` in a variable, so when the next row is fetched `@prevDateNew` has the value of the previous row's `datenew`

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 t1.*
,coalesce(timestampdiff(MINUTE,t2.dt,t1.dt),0) as tdiff 
from t t1 left join t t2
on t1.id = t2.id+1
order by t1.id
```

As you are only looking for a difference between the current row and the next, you can join on the next row and calculate the time difference in minutes.

Note: This assumes there are no missing id's in the table. You might have to change the `join` condition if there were missing id's.

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dcae/15

Comment: it doesnot work for me and it gives err : Can't reopen table: 't1'

Comment: you should replace `t` with your tablename. Also change the column names as per your table.

Comment: i recalled the table is : "ttt" and use this query////////// select 
 t1.*
,coalesce(timestampdiff(MINUTE,t2.DATENEW,t1.DATENEW),0) as tdiff 
from ttt t1 left join ttt t2
on t1.id = t2.id+1
order by t1.id

Comment: and here is the error again :::Error Code : 1137
Can't reopen table: 't1'                                                                                            **note: iam using the SQLyog and table "ttt" is temporarily created by previous query

Comment: do you get a error? and are the column names correct..as per your question `id` should be replaced with `ticketid`

Comment: ya i re changed again to ticketid insted of id ,but the same error :::Error Code : 1137
Can't reopen table: 't1'