# Get the delta time between two rows in MySQL using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```sql
select 
    event_time, argument 
from 
    mysql.general_log 
where 
    argument <> 'SHOW WARNINGS' 
order by 
    event_time;
```

and I was wondering if it is possible to add a column that would say what the time diff between rows would be for each row?

Similar to [Getting the Delta between the rows on SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980712/getting-the-delta-between-the-rows-on-sql) and [time difference between two rows - mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276257/time-difference-between-two-rows-mysql) (uses PHP) by for using only SQL in MySQL (no PHP)

Comment: What MySQL version you use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate time difference between current and previous row in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040867/how-to-calculate-time-difference-between-current-and-previous-row-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select event_time, argument,
       timestampdiff(second, lag(event_time) over (order by event_time), event_time) as diff
from mysql.general_log
where argument <> 'SHOW WARNINGS'
order by event_time ;
```

In older versions of MySQL, you can use:

```
select gl.event_time, gl.argument,
       timestampdiff(second,
                     (select gl2.event_time
                      from mysql.general_log gl2
                      where gl2.event_time < gl.event_time
                      order by gl2.event_time desc
                      limit 1
                    ) as diff
from mysql.general_log gl
where gl.argument <> 'SHOW WARNINGS'
order by gl.event_time ;
```

Comment: Syntax error somwhere  SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'over (order by event_time), event_time) as diff
from mysql.general_log
where a' at line 2

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano . . . What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: 8 client 5.7 server

Answer (score 0):

Marking as duplicate, but I'll put the answer here in case someone wants to do a similar analysis for mysql.general_log

```sql
select argument, event_time, timestampdiff( MICROSECOND ,prevdatenew, event_time) as diff
from (
    select argument, event_time, @prevDateNew as prevdatenew, 
      @prevDateNew := event_time
      from mysql.general_log
    where argument <> 'SHOW WARNINGS'
    order by event_time 
) t1
where argument not like 'SET auto%' and argument not like '/*%'
-- order by diff desc
```